# css background image not showing not a path issue

Tags: css, background, background-image

Most of the many related issues seem to be with paths, but externally linking and not using a stylesheet it still won't work. Using an image in the same folder as the code also doesn't work.  The CSS validates on codebeautify.

```css
.logo { background: url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/128/keditbookmarks.png") left center no-repeat; background-size: 50% 50%; width: 100px; }
```

```html
<div class="logo">some text</div>
<div>random stuff before <span class="logo">star</span><br>
    empty span <span class="logo"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>after<BR>
    <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/128/keditbookmarks.png"/></div>

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mousey/uhcpcy7k/)
```

Comment: I disagree that it's a duplicate question, the answer is relevant to more than one question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **non-UTF-8 space** or may be a `&nbsp;` after the `background:`. Replace it with correct space.

Please see the below output of `encodeURIComponent` using Chrome:

[image]

The first one is my text. The second one being yours from the fiddle.

```css
.logo {
  background: url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/128/keditbookmarks.png") left center no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">some text</div>
<div>random stuff before <span class="logo">star</span>
  <br>empty span <span class="logo"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>after
  <BR>
  <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/1620/crystal_project/128/keditbookmarks.png" />
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9060o2j/**

Comment: that's great - is there a way to find these without inspecting the DOM? Anything than can be searched for in a text editor or other programming tool or validation? I wonder if this is why codebeautify validated it but w3.org gave odd errors.   For an unknown reason \0a and variants do not work inside `:before {content :` css in my code, but in the css in my example the space wasn't needed so I just deleted it.